# Android - How to get the list of Hardware Buttons of the smartphone device where my app is running

Tags: java, android, android-hardware

According to the fact that (of course) an app can run on different devices, I'm searching a way to list the hardware buttons available on the smartphone.

Usually Volume, Power are always there. Sometimes a button that launch camera is present, sometimes a button that launch "Google Now" is present, etc...
How can my app knows which are available?

Final target for me is to use an hardware button to perform a precise action of my app. 
I implemented it with volume button, but it works only if screen is on and my app is in foreground, while I need to do that also when screen is off and my app is in background.

Comment: As far as i know, there is no way you can get the list of hardware keys. If you have found a way, Please update it here.

Comment: I didn't find a way... sorry

Comment: @Fausto70 Did you get any solution?

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't...